# While loop to test if file exists in bash script

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am trying to create a loop to prompt the user to create a file. If the file already exists, it will keep prompting the user till the user enters a file that does not exist. But it doesn't go to my elif condition. Anyone able to help?

```
FILENAME=newfile
SEARCHFILES=/root/simulate/$filename

while [ ! -f "$SEARCHFILES" ]
do
 read -p "Enter file name to create: " FILENAME
 if [ ! -f "$SEARCHFILES" ]; then
  touch /root/simulate/$FILENAME
  break
 elif [ -f "$SEARCHFILES" ]; then
  read -p "Please enter a different file name as $FILENAME already exist: " FILENAME
 else
  touch "/root/simulate/$FILENAME"
 fi
done
```

Comment: You don't change the value of `SEARCHFILES` inside the loop.

Comment: Is there anyway i can change the value such that it reads the user input?

Comment: run your code with `set -x` active. You'll see what is being processed and when. Also note that filename and FILENAME are two different variables and are not the same. Don't you just want another `SEARCHFILES=` statement after you prompt the user? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO.

First, don't use uppercase vars. Convention reserves those for system stuff like IFS.

Second, always try to simplify. Fewer moving parts make for easier to understand logic.

```
dir=/root/simulate
while read -p "Enter file name to create: " fname
do    file="$dir/$fname"
      if [[ -e "$file" ]] # -f won't work if it's a directory, etc
      then echo "File exists, please try again."
           continue
      fi
      touch "$file"
      break
done
```